# What does 'active' in importdescriptors do/mean?

Tags: output-script-descriptors

this is what documentation says '(boolean, optional, default=false) Set this descriptor to be the active descriptor for the corresponding output type/externality'

Should it be used with addr descriptor ? why? why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active descriptors are ones from which new addresses are drawn (through the `getnewaddress` RPC, new receive addresses in the GUI, change addresses if internal, ...).

Active descriptors must be ranged (have a KEY expression with a '*' in it). `addr()` descriptors are never ranged, so they cannot be active.